# How do i add rhproxy to the ACPI Table

Tags: windows, windows-10-iot-core, acpi

i try to use the SPI Bus of my custom board threw windows 10 IoT Enterprise. I use a Intel Atom X5 E3930 CPU on a Congatec SA5 module.
i found the rhproxy driver in the system folder and checkt the boot option of it and i checked if he is running.
-> the result is the proxy is runnung but i can't find it in the device tree and my software example could not open any connection to the SPI device. The Handle of the device is still NULL

i checked the ACPI Table and could not find any entries about the rhproxy. 
 now my question.
how can i get the ACPI entry for rhproxy or is there any way to modify the ACPI table.

regards

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide user mode Universal Windows Platform (UWP) API access to simple buses like I2C, GPIO and SPI, you need make sure that ACPI table in your UEFI firmware contains appropriate entries for RHProxy. Please refer to [user mode access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enable-usermode-access) for more information. You may try to create a .NET app that uses AcpiGenFx to generate ACPI tables, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/generate-acpi-tables-by-using-acpigenfx).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer, it was very useful for me.

now i can see my rhproxy at the device manager but i can't get access to my spi bus.
my Spi bus is connected over an PCI bus to my cpu, how do i tell the rhproxy ther will be a device.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        x86Platform platform = Platforms.Createx86Platform(
      //ArmPlatform Platform = Platforms.CreateArmPlatform(
            OEMID: "MSFT",
            OEMTableID: "EDK2",
            CreatorID: "MSFT",
            Revision: 1,
            FileName: "SSDT"
            );

        platform.SSDT = true;

        var rh = platform.AddGenericDevice("RHPX", "MSFT8000", "MSFT8000", 1);

        rh.AddSerialPort(AutoAcpi.SerialPortType.Serial, "SPI1", "7270", 0x5AC2);


        platform.WriteAsl();
```

}

this is the code i used to define the proxy.

thanks for your help
Regards